# JBoss 5.x and Axis2

Tags: jboss, apache-axis

What libraries are required to run a Web Service Client that has been generated from Axis 2 on JBoss.  So far I have not found anything in my searches.

I assume that the following error:

org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: Failed to create a new SAX parser

Is due to the fact that I have place every jar file from Axis lib folder into my projects

**My Solution**

Did it the hard way - added and subtracted jars from my lib directory until I got it to deploy and run with no exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Is what you have pasted the root cause of the stack trace? In case it is **not**, the problem is that probably your app is deployed with xerces related jar files in it (ex: xercesImpl-x.x.x.jar). JBoss is shipped with the xerces jars in its JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed folder. If the same classes are deployed with your web app this may result in class loading issues.

You can try to remove the xerces libs from your app and then test the web service client again.

Cheers!